# Nusselt number in Rayleigh-Bénard convection derivation

Tags: convection

I read, that for a box with length L, with heated bottom and cooled top and boundary layers of thickness $\delta$, the Nusselt number Nu can be approximated as
$$
\text{Nu}= 
\begin{cases}
    1,& \text{if } \text{Ra} \ll \text{Ra}_\text{crit}\\
    \frac{L}{2 \delta},   & \text{if Ra} \gg \text{Ra}_\text{crit}\\
\end{cases}
$$

where Ra is the Rayleigh number.
The first case is obvious, but how can one derive the second case?